# How to trigger an angularjs animation from a controller method?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I would like to trigger an angular animation from a controller method.

I have come up with something that I am not satisfied with (see code below).

The issue is that for my animation to work, I need to track the state of a $scope variable i.e. `$scope.shake`:

```
$scope.signin = function (formCtrl) {
    $scope.shake = false;
    if ($scope.credentials) {
        signinService.signin($scope.credentials, function (status, memberRole) {
                $scope.shake = false;
                //TODO: necessary to check status?
                if (status === 200) {
                    var memberType;
                    if (memberRole === 'ROLE_BASIC_PARENTS') {
                        memberType = 'parents';
                    }
                    if (memberRole === 'ROLE_BASIC_CHILDCARE_WORKER') {
                        memberType = 'childcare-worker';
                    }
                    $rootScope.globals = {
                        memberType: memberType,
                        authenticated: 'OK'
                    }

                    $cookies.globalsMemberType = $rootScope.globals.memberType;
                    $cookies.globalsAuthenticated = $rootScope.globals.authenticated;

                    $state.go('dashboard', {memberType: memberType});
                }
            },
            function () {
                $scope.shake = true;
            });
    }
    else {
        $scope.shake = true;
    }
};

<form ng-class="{shake: shake}" name="formCtrl" ng-submit="signin(formCtrl)" novalidate>
```

Can someone please advise a cleaner solution?

**edit 1**:

Here is the css code as requested:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    12.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
        transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    }

    37.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
        transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    }

    62.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
        transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    }

    87.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
        transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    12.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
        transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    }

    37.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
        transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    }

    62.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
        transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    }

    87.5% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
        transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.shake {
    -webkit-animation: shake 400ms ease-in-out;
    animation: shake 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the form to shake until they fill in its fields?

Comment: Hi, No I want the form to shake if there is any issue: wrong credentials **or** blank fields. I would like to trigger the animation programmatically from the controller.

Comment: @balteo can you add your css code?

Comment: @Matho: I have added the css code to my post.

Comment: Please explain what you dislike about having a scope variable manage your animations. Seems as if you would have to manage some kind of on/off mechanism no matter what. Or do you NOT want your form to shake until they re-submit? rather just for a time period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up using (see code below). It is an adaptation of Liamnes's proposed solution.

```
angular.module('signin')
    .controller('SigninCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$cookies', '$state', '$animate', 'signinService', function ($scope, $rootScope, $cookies, $state, $animate, signinService) {

        var setPersonalInfo = function (param) {
            return signinService.setPersonalInfo(param.headers, $rootScope);
        };
        var goToDashboard = function (memberType) {
            $state.go('dashboard', {memberType: memberType});
        };
        var reportProblem = function () {
            $scope.formCtrl.username.$setValidity('username.wrong', false);
            $scope.formCtrl.password.$setValidity('password.wrong', false);
            $scope.$broadcast('SIGNIN_ERROR');
        };
        var resetForm = function(formCtrl){
            formCtrl.username.$setValidity('username.wrong', true);
            formCtrl.password.$setValidity('password.wrong', true);
        };

        $scope.signin = function (formCtrl) {

            resetForm(formCtrl);

            if (formCtrl.$valid) {
                signinService.signin($scope.credentials).then(setPersonalInfo).then(goToDashboard).catch(reportProblem);
            }
            else {
                $scope.$broadcast('SIGNIN_ERROR');
            }
        }
    }])
    .directive('shakeThat', ['$animate', function ($animate) {
        return {
            require: '^form',
            scope: {
                signin: '&'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, form) {
                scope.$on('SIGNIN_ERROR', function () {
                    $animate.addClass(element, 'shake').then(function () {
                        $animate.removeClass(element, 'shake');
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<form shake-that name="formCtrl" ng-submit="signin(formCtrl)" novalidate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. I like the accuracy of Matho's solution but I ended up adapting Liames 's solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you wrap the form in a directive, and trigger the animation via an event. e.g. in the controller you would do:

```
$scope.$broadcast('FORM_ERROR');
```

and in the directive, do something more like

```
scope.$on('FORM_ERROR', function() { // code to trigger animation goes here });
```

Makes sense to handle this as an event for me, because then it has a strict lifecycle; event is dispatched, event gets handled. A scope variable would hang around, even though it no longer has any meaning. You might even need code to 'reset' it back to its original state so the animation can be triggered again, which adds unneeded complexity.

Comment: but how would you turn it off? If you create a `FORM_VALID` event, what advantage does OP get over setting a scope variable?

Comment: The code that triggers the animation should clean up after itself, you wouldn't need a separate event. For instance, you could create a callback for the `animationend` event and remove the class triggering the animation there.

Comment: But then what is the advantage of using an event. A callback would be simpler and do the trick just as well.

Comment: Separation of concerns, mainly. The controller shouldn't care about the specifics of how the animation is triggered. The directive shouldn't care about why the error occurred. Keeping your DOM manipulation and business logic separate stops things getting confusing. The best way to do this in Angular is to use a directive, and the only way to communicate between a controller and a directive is an event!

Comment: Oh, I assumed OP was concerned with functionality. What makes you think OP is concerned with SoC?

Comment: The askee came up with something that worked, but also expressed a dissatisfaction with with the solution, wanting something 'cleaner'. As such I feel a discussion of best practices is appropriate.

Comment: "The issue is that for my animation to work, I need to track the state of a $scope variable i.e. $scope.shake" With your solution, he would still have to keep track of state somehow to turn off the affect. You have separated the UI from Controller (which doesn't sound like good SoC, but you have not freed him from maintaining state. If not in a scope variable, then how? Unless I'm missing something, your comment section is where the real value would go.

Comment: "the only way to communicate between a controller and a directive is an event" <--not entirely true! If the controller is specified as an option in the directive or if it is required, the controller gets passed as a 4th argument in the link option.

Answer (score 1):

You will have another problem your animation isn't reset after the first fail, so consecutive fails won't execute the animation again. I'm afraid that there is no way to do this using pure CSS.

What you should do first is to use the validation services provided by Angular and then separate the logic of the error animation.

[**Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/w8fLjj?p=preview) is the working solution, with the Prefix util factory working just fine.

- First check `form.$invalid` inside your `signin(formCtrl)` function, if the form is $invalid or the response from the service returns a login error, then call a function which will handle the animation.

---

```
  $scope.signin = function(form){
    if(form.$invalid){
      $scope.animateError();
    }
  };
```

---

- Change the CSS to only add the animation timing function and duration.
  So when the `showAnimationError` function is called it will take the form element, and add the style `animationName`/ `webkitAnimationName` with the value `shake`.

Also remember to add a event listener for the animation end, so you can clean this style, for consecutive calls on `showAnimationError`

```
/* css */
.shake {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-duration: 400ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

---

```
$scope.animateError = function(){
  if(!resetAnimationHandler){
    addResetAnimationHandler();
  }
  myForm.style[prefixUtil.animationName] = 'shake';
};
```

I hope this helps you